# Предача объекта ,как аргумент метода

Tags: javascript, php

Привет.С Новым Годом.
Цель -заменить предачу множества аргумента одним.
Припустим есть метод:

```
fn:function(object){
return object.arg1+object.arg2
}
```

Конечно, можно припустим создать объект

```
obj=new Construct(arg1,......);
```

и передать его при вызове метода fn(obj).
Теперь задача-как обойти процедуру создание объекта отдельно от вызова метода.
Я хочу что-то вроде
fn(new Construct(arg1,......)).Как теперь использовать созданный объект.
Но так возвращается прошлая проблема-передача множества аргументов.
Прошу немного подсказать как лучше поступать в таких случаях.
 Можно пример и на php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

а чем не устравивает передача массива? а в функции уже пусть разбирается массив по частям

Comment: вариант,просто интересный данный случай.Просто пускай есть класс, который генерирует объект.